# How do I stop the screen from updating?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a calculator in pygame but when I click the button, I want the number to stay on the screen but instead of staying on the screen, the number just appears when my mouse is clicked. When I release it, the numbers disappears. Does anyone know a solution for this?
My code:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Calculator")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font1 = pygame.font.Font("c:/Users/oreni/OneDrive/Masaüstü/sprites/minecraft.ttf", 100)

one = 1

one_main = font1.render(str(one), False, "black")
one_main_r = one_main.get_rect(center = (75,100))

one_button = pygame.Surface((142.5,142.5))
one_button.fill("white")
one_button_r = one_button.get_rect(topleft = (0,160))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.fill("black")
    screen.blit(one_button,one_button_r)

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if one_button_r.collidepoint(event.pos):
            screen.blit(one_main,one_main_r)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Why are you blacking out the screen on every tick?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to redraw the scene in each frame. You need to draw the text in the application loop. Set a variable that indicates that the image should be drawn when the mouse is clicked, and draw the image according to that variable:

```py
draw_r = False
run = True

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if one_button_r.collidepoint(event.pos):
                draw_r = True

    screen.fill("black")
    screen.blit(one_button,one_button_r)
    if draw_r:
        screen.blit(one_main, one_main_r)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)